# Datatool - Fill Variable (name in first row) with value of second row

Tags: datatool

I have a csv with 2 rows. the first row contains names and the second row the value. i want to create variables (tried it with newcommand) that have the Name of the first row and define them with the value of the second row. the final csv will contain around 50 rows.

here's my Code:
it seems that it overwrites the same variable again and again ...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,} 


\begin{filecontents*}{Unnamed1.csv}
Voltage   ,   14 V
Current   ,   1  A
MoreText  ,   something more is written here
Date      ,   2017/03/08
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{Test}{Unnamed1.csv}


\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{Test}{\name=name,\value=value}
{
\newcommand{\name}{\value}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Rewritten answer now the question is clearer.)

The problem with

```
\DTLforeach{Test}{\name=name,\value=value}
{
\newcommand{\name}{\value}
}
```

Is that `\name` is repeatedly redefined on each iteration by the assignment. This also just tries to define `\name` rather than construct a control sequence formed from the definition of `\name`. The `etoolbox` package provides ways of defining a command given the name (without the initial backslash). For example, `\csdef{Voltage}{14 V}` defines the command `\Voltage` with the replacement text `14 V`. In this case, you want the control sequence name obtained from `\name` and the replacement text obtained from the definition of `\value`, so what you really need is `\cslet{\name}{\value}`, which creates a new command formed from the definition of `\name` and assigns it to the definition of `\value` (so it retains the correct definition after `\value` is redefined in the next iteration of the loop).

A couple of notes: `\value` is already defined by the LaTeX kernel (it obtains the value of a counter), so its better to use another command name (say, `\Value`) to avoid breaking anything. You also need to trim the [spurious space](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/datatool.shtml#csnote) from the data.

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Unnamed1.csv}
name,value
Voltage,14 V
Current,1 A
MoreText,something more is written here
Date,2017/03/08
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb{Test}{Unnamed1.csv}
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{Test}{\Name=name,\Value=value}
{%
 \cslet{\Name}{\Value}%
}

Voltage: \Voltage.

Current: \Current.

MoreText: \MoreText.

Date: \Date.

\end{document}
```

[image: Voltage: 14 V. Current: 1 A. MoreText: something more is written here. Date: 2017/03/08.]

Comment: Hello Nicola, thanks for your answer! Exactly, i want a command whose Name is read from the first row and define the value of the second row to that. Unfortunately i have around 50 rows not only 2. ist just a list with lots of info like: t1 = 50 K, U1 = 12 V etc.

Comment: @Jonas Could you add a few sample rows (say, 4 rows) to your question to illustrate it.

Comment: i added it to the original question, thank you!

Comment: Hello @Nicola Talbot, i am reading multiple files. I tried to add a Counter to the \Name so everything is unique, but i can't get it to work. My code:  \cslet{\expandafter\csname\Name\arabic{somecounter}\endcsname}{\Value}

Comment: @Jonas What do you actually want the new command to be called? Suppose `\Name` is `Voltage` and `somecounter` has the value 1, then your code tries to create a control sequence whose name is given by `\csname Voltage1\endcsname` so you're actually trying to create `\csname \csname Voltage1\endcsname\endcsname`. Did you intend `\cslet{\Name\arabic{somecounter}}{\Value}` instead? Which would create the command whose name is `Voltage1` that needs to be accessed using `\csuse{Voltage1}`. (`\Voltage1` would be treated as two tokens `\Voltage` followed by `1`.)

Answer (score 4):

Is something like this, with the `readarray` package, sufficient?

**REVISION**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.dat}
First, Last, Birthday 
John, Doe, 01/01/68 
\end{filecontents*}
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand\assigndat[1]{%
  \readarraysepchar{,}%
  \readdef{#1}\mydata%
  \readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]%
  \setcounter{mycount}{0}%
  \whiledo{\themycount<\ncols}{%
    \stepcounter{mycount}%
    \edef\tmp{\myarray[1,\themycount]}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\xdef\expandafter\csname\tmp\endcsname{%
      \myarray[2,\themycount]}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\assigndat{myfile.dat}
\First

\Last

\Birthday
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfile}
First, Last, Birthday 
John, Doe, 01/01/68 
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand\assigndat[1]{%
  \edef\tmp{\myarray[1,#1]}
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\csname\tmp\endcsname{\myarray[2,#1]}
}
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{myfile.tex}\mydata
\readarray*\mydata\myarray[-,\ncols]
Column 3 title is ``\myarray[1,3]''.

Column 3 data is ``\myarray[2,3]''

\assigndat{1}\First

\assigndat{2}\Last

\assigndat{3}\Birthday
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Unfortunately i don't want to "hard code" the items of my list. There is a 100% chance, that there are changes made in the future and by defining variables inside the document it would not matter where the data is written as long as the name is not changed.

Comment: @Jonas Please see my revision, if this is more in line with your desires.

Comment: Hello! It doesnt compile on my System. i get an undefined control sequence for \assigndat. I'll try to understand why tomorrow. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Jonas Make sure you copied the text properly from my answer.  Clearly, you can see `\assigndat` defined in the preamble.  Thus, it should be defined when you invoke it in the document.

Comment: @Jonas also make sure your version of `readarray` is up to date.